# Scala cats, flatMap on cartesian?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cartesian

Given:

```
import cats.syntax.cartesian._

type M[X] = Future[Either[Error, X]]
val ma: M[A] = ???
val mb: M[B] = ???
```

I know I can do that:

```
def doStuff(a: A, b: B): C = ???
val result: M[C] = (ma |@| mb).map(doStuff)
```

But how do I flatMap? There's no `flatMap` in the `CartesianBuilder`s.

```
def doFancyStuff(a: A, b: B): M[C] = ???
val result: M[C] = (ma |@| mb).flatMap(doFancyStuff)
```

Comment: That's because `CartesianBuilder` is a `Semigroup[A]`, not a `Monad[A]`.

Comment: Little remark: Scaladoc for cats.syntax.cartesian has a deprecation warning: "Deprecated  (Since version 1.0.0-RC1) use cats.syntax.semigroupal instead" Is it intended?

Comment: @Andrey They switched `|@|` to `mapN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem is that it's awkward to `flatMap` on a `Future[Either[Error, X]]` in the sense of `EitherT[Future, Error, X]`-monad stack, because the original `flatMap` of the `Future` gets in the way, and the compiler isn't looking for a monad instance that could handle the combination of `Future` and `Either` simultaneously. However, if you wrap the futures in `EitherT`, everything works smoothly.

**For cats 1.0.1**

In the following, `(a,b).tupled` corresponds to `Cartesian.product(a, b)`, and `(a, b).mapN` corresponds to the deprecated `(a |@| b).map`.

Given types `A`, `B`, `C`, `Error`, the following code snippets compile under cats 1.0.1:

If you want to preserve your definition of `M` (you probably should), then you
can avoid the above mentioned problems by wrapping everything in `EitherT` and then
extracting the `value`:

```
import scala.util.Either
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global // required by Monad[Future]
import cats.instances.future._                            // Monad for `Future`
import cats.syntax.apply._                                // `tupled` and `mapN`
import cats.data.EitherT                                  // EitherT monad transformer

type M[X] = Future[Either[Error, X]]
val ma: M[A] = ???
val mb: M[B] = ???

def doStuff(a: A, b: B): C = ???
val result1: M[C] = (EitherT(ma), EitherT(mb)).mapN(doStuff).value

def doFancyStuff(a: A, b: B): M[C] = ???
val result2: M[C] = (for {
  ab <- (EitherT(ma), EitherT(mb)).tupled
  c <- EitherT(doFancyStuff(ab._1, ab._2))
} yield c).value
```

However, if this seems too awkward, and you can adjust the definition of `M`,
the following variant could be slightly shorter:

```
import scala.util.Either
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global // required by Monad[Future]
import cats.instances.future._                            // Monad for `Future`
import cats.syntax.apply._                                // `tupled` and `mapN`
import cats.data.EitherT                                  // EitherT monad transformer

type M[X] = EitherT[Future, Error, X]
val ma: M[A] = ??? // either adjust signatures, or wrap result in EitherT(res)
val mb: M[B] = ???

def doStuff(a: A, b: B): C = ???
val result1: M[C] = (ma, mb).mapN(doStuff)

def doFancyStuff(a: A, b: B): M[C] = ???
val result2: M[C] = (ma, mb).tupled.flatMap{
  case (a, b) => doFancyStuff(a, b)
}
```

This is because `(ma, mb).tupled` builds a `M[(A, B)]`, where `M` is the previously mentioned monad stack, which then can be easily `flatMap`ped with a `(A, B) => M[C]` function to `M[C]`.

**For older versions with `Cartesian` (untested)**

Assuming that `(ma, mb).tupled` corresponds to the deprecated `Cartesian.product` and `(ma, mb).mapN` corresponds to the deprecated `(ma |@| mb).map`, the two definitions of `result1` and `result2` in the above code snippet for 1.0.1 translate to:

```
val result1: M[C] = (ma |@| mb).map(doStuff)
val result2: M[C] = Cartesian[M].product(ma, mb).flatMap{ 
  case (a, b) => doFancyStuff(a, b) 
}
```

Again, this works only because `Cartesian[M].product(ma, mb)` builds an `M[(A, B)]` from `M[A]` and `M[B]`, where `M[X]` is defined as `EitherT[Future, Error, X]`. If it were defined as `Future[Either[Error, X]]`, then the `flatMap` would be invoked on the `Future`, and instead of `doFancyStuff` we would have to pass something like `Either[Error, (A, B)] => Future[Either[Error, C]]`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Your 2nd snippet worked for me. I had EitherT but missed it in the question. Luckly I could upgrade my cats, so `tupled.flatMap` is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Vituel Ah, all right. Then you could choose the shortest version out of three, good. :) Any comments on whether the third snippet would compile? I really didn't bother to create a separate project with an older cats version just for that.

Comment: Yep, your 3rd snipped compiles fine in cats 0.9.0.

Comment: @Vituel Ah, ok, thanks for checking that. What happened to the other `Traverse`-thing in the end? The implementation of `Traverse[Seq]` certainly did compile in 1.0.1. Was it not usable for some reason?